# HTML5 video never finishes loading when cache is enabled (in Chrome)

Tags: google-chrome, caching, video, html5-video

I have a simple video on my site, nothing more than:

```
<video poster="...">
  <source src="some/path/to/file.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

When I'm trying to load video while devtools are open and checkbox "disable cache" is checked, following happens:

[image: cache disabled]

And video plays normally.

But when checkbox "disable cache" is unchecked, I see this:

[image: cache enabled]

Just "loadstart", and nothing more, video is stuck forever in this state.

Tried multiple times, and I can say for sure that cache state is the only thing that makes difference.
In Firefox corresponding option has no effect and video plays normally in both cases.

Here are headers of request with cache disabled (omitting User-Agent and cookies):

```
Host: localhost:9910
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Accept-Encoding: identity;q=1, *;q=0
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:9910/
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,ru;q=0.6,uk;q=0.4
Range: bytes=0-
```

With cache enabled, headers of first request (which returns 206):

```
Host: localhost:9910
Connection: keep-alive
Accept-Encoding: identity;q=1, *;q=0
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:9910/
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,ru;q=0.6,uk;q=0.4
Range: bytes=0-
```

And second request (which returns 200):

```
Host: localhost:9910
Connection: keep-alive
Accept-Encoding: identity;q=1, *;q=0
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:9910/
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,ru;q=0.6,uk;q=0.4
Range: bytes=360448-393474
If-Range: Mon, 12 Jun 2017 13:07:36 GMT
```

Besides obvious `Pragma: no-cache` and `Cache-Control: no-cache` in first case, it's easy to see that in third case there is different value of `Range` header, and also `If-Range` header added. I read [about it](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7233#section-3.2), but I still don't understand what exactly going on: response on this 3-rd request contains `last-modified: Mon, 12 Jun 2017 13:07:36 GMT` – equal to `If-Range` value, so, if I understand correctly, resource should be considered unchanged and by spec 206 with partial data should be returned.

I'm not good with all this headers stuff, so my questions are:

- why this request with `If-Range` appears?
- why video does not finish loading, despite all requests succeed?
- what should I do to make video play, after all? Should I request it somehow differently on frontend, or it's a question to server's settings?

Comment: if the video encoded with the MOOV atom at the start (using ffmpeg or qt-fastart etc)? Might be a problem that the metadata is taking a while to be available when not cached

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it was somehow caused by server. Don't know what exactly our backend devs have fixed, but at least it's not a browser problem.

Anyway, still interested how is it possible that video can't load despite that all requests succeed. What could it lack to start playing?